# Fastest way to to take coordinates from model space, to canonical coordinates space in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Like many 3d graphical programs, I have a bunch of objects that have their own model coordinates (from -1 to 1 in x, y, and z axis).  Then, I have a matrix that takes it from model coordinates to world coordinates (using the location, rotation, and scale of the object being drawn).  Finally, I have a second matrix to turn those world coordinates into canonical coordinates that OopenGL ES 2.0 will use to draw to the screen.

So, because one object can contain many vertices, all of which use the same transform into both world space, and canonical coordinates, it's faster to calculate the product of those two matrices once, and put each vertex through the resulting matrix, rather than putting each vertex through both matrices.

But, as far as I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way in OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders to have it calculate the matrix once, and keep using it until the one of the two matrices used until glUniformMatrix4fv() (or another function to set a uniform) is called.  So it seems like the only way to calculate the matrix once would be to do it on the CPU, and then result to the GPU using a uniform.  Otherwise, when something like:

```
gl_Position = uProjection * uMV * aPosition;
```

it will calculate it over and over again, which seems like it would waste time.

So, which way is usually considered standard?  Or is there a different way that I am completely missing?  As far as I could tell, the shader used to implement the OpenGL ES 1.1 pipeline in the OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide only used one matrix, so is that used more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the correct OpenGL term for "canonical coordinates" is clip space.

Second, it should be this:

```
gl_Position = uProjection * (uMV * aPosition);
```

What you posted does a matrix/matrix multiply followed by a matrix/vector multiply. This version does 2 matrix/vector multiplies. That's a substantial difference.

You're using shader-based hardware; how you handle matrices is up to you. There is nothing that is "considered standard"; you do what you best need to do.

That being said, unless you are doing lighting in model space, you will often need some intermediary between model space and 4D homogeneous clip-space. This is the space you transform the positions and normals into in order to compute the light direction, dot(N, L), and so forth.

Personally, I wouldn't suggest world space for reasons that [I explain thoroughly here.](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Positioning/Tut07%20The%20Perils%20of%20World%20Space.html) But whether it's world space, camera space, or something else, you will generally have some intermediate space that you need positions to be in. At which point, the above code becomes necessary, and thus there is no time wasted.

Comment: the link for the explanation no longer exists.  Would you update?